# How to have a read-only broadcast view in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I want to originate messages only from an internal process from the server then outgoing to clients and because of SignalR flexibility, I'm worried XSS could easily send a message "myhub.addMessage" and send in garbage that I don't want broadcasted. For example, I have 50 people on a page listening for message from SignalR Hub. They don't have an explicit way to send a message via the GUI, however, a half-wit could easily hack some script together and start sending in messages for all to see.

Its kind of like having a chat room in other words but you want to prevent people from sending messages. You only want them to hear. Makes sense?

Comment: If you took signalr out of the equation and only used webservice calls what would you do?

Comment: @dfowler You created this and you know you can do XSS to "addMessage" isn't that correct or no? How do you prevent someone from doing "addMessage" through JavaScript by simply doing a view source, grab it, put a base tag locally, then put some script in there? I was hoping there was some c# flag or setting on the class that would make it read only.

Comment: You kinda ignored my question.

Comment: Not trying to ignore you @dfowler. I think very highly of your efforts. Your question is really saying, "roll your own way of doing it." Yes, I can but the point was to use a nice framework to do the broadcasting yet not allow chats to be posted in. Basically half of your solution to allow for the real time updates but just disabling people from the ability of doing XSS. I'll look at your source on Git if that's your final answer. No worries.

Comment: Implementing some kind of security where you pass token to the server for ever command could also work if that is possible.

Comment: @kitgui.com I wasn't asking you to roll your own solution, I was just looking for an answer to the question. I think it'd be awesome if we had something in signalr for this but I'm just asking you what you do today (if anything).

Comment: I'll take a crack at it and update you as soon as I get some time @dfowler. I would love to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the AddMessage Method from the Hub.

That's really it.

If you still need the functionality from the web, then you will need to set up some kind of security to check against. SingalR doesn't have this built in yet.

Or if you need it only from outside the web (say the server just publishes events) then the outside of hub methods will do you fine (See Broadcasting over a Hub from outside of a Hub at the bottom of the page: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs )

Another option is to check authentication at the start of any given action. You do have access to cookies. But I am unsure about the normal Membership System as I don't use it. Since you have access to cookies, here is the pattern I am using for authentication:

```
public SomeHub : Hub
{
    public void RandomAction()
    {
        if(!CheckCookie("Role Required"))
        {
            //In here we have what happens when there is
            //  a cookie that is associated with the right Role Required
        }
    }
}
```

You might be able to use the Membership system in CheckCookie, however this might help:

```
    string CookieName = "Website Authentication";
    string vReturn = null;
    HttpCookie vCookie = null;
    if(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Any(t => t == CookieName))
        vCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[CookieName];
    if(vCookie != null)
        vReturn = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(vCookie.Value).Name;
    return vReturn;
```

The membership cookie name is not that, it's just a filler.

Comment: How do I do that on the current framework as I want to use it still on other pages for the standard behavior? Code example would greatly help. Thanks.

Comment: Ew, in that case you are going to need to add some security code to hook in. You can use cookies for this, but since there is no "PreAction" call you are stuck calling a "Validate" method at the start of each Action. If you only allow people to get to the page in question after logging in with the ASP Membership system, you should be able to use that.

Comment: I'll see about sample code when I get home. I think I have some but it does not use the Membership Provider system, but the structure is pretty generic.

Comment: I give you a point for trying as I don't think this is possible with the current setup.

Comment: Not easily. You have access to cookies, so you can check them. Let me add something that might help